# Simple NLP in Java

Tags: java, oracle, nlp

I need to develop a Java application that will scan/search a given string against a user defined criteria/filter and return true or false. The user criteria/filter will be

Keyword
Regular expression
and user can define multiple AND & OR filters and NOT as well. Below are some examples:

```
Contains "Test" AND Contains "Java" OR Contains "Stackoverflow"
Not Contains "Warning"
Contains "Regex here"
```

Since its a single column and I have Oracle database at the backend, one way to do this would be to allow user to define the criteria in plain SQL where clause syntax and rather than performing the search at the application, I could just pass it to database as following:

```
SELECT col1 from (select 'String to search Java Test' as col1 from dual) DUMMY where col1 like 'String%' and col1 like '%Java%';
```

Not sure if this would be the best approach or if there any good NLP libraries that could do this. Would appreciate any feedback commenmts

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) to index string into memory, and use [Lucene query grammar](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) to search.

There is a full example: [lucene-in-memory-text-search-example](http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more how this could help with my requirement. Isnt it just searching some text? I need to convert the filters written in plain english to something I could use in Java

Comment: I think you can use the raw lucene grammar to search, but firstly you need to index your search content. Your user need to learn about lucene grammar. Also you can define your own DSL to translate to lucene grammar.